# How to get category link without a database query

Tags: query, categories

I use Wordpress 4.3.1 with [PremiumPress Business Directory Theme](http://www.premiumpress.com/wordpress-business-directory/). The theme's homepage renders a list of categories using code that's basically:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'     => THEME_TAXONOMY, // 'listing'
    'orderby'      => 'name',
    'show_count'   => 0,
    'pad_counts'   => 1,
    'hierarchical' => 0,
    'title_li'     => '',
    'include'   => $xcc,
    'hide_empty'   => 0,
);

$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $LINK = get_term_link($category->slug, THEME_TAXONOMY);
    // render with $LINK...
}
```

Using [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/), I noticed that each category causes the following database query:

```
SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'listing' AND t.slug = '%d7%94%d7%91%d7%a2%d7%94-%d7%95%d7%99%d7%a6%d7%99%d7%a8%d7%94' LIMIT 1
(...), get_term_link, get_term_by
```

I tried using `get_category_link`, but it also causes a similar query.

- Is there a way to get the category link without triggering a database query?
- If not, can these somehow be retrieved in a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's down to how you're using `get_term_link()` - since you're passing a slug, WordPress can't locate the term in it's internal cache (terms are indexed by ID), so it grabs it directly from the db.

To use the cache, pass the ID. Better yet, pass just the object:

```
get_term_link( $category ); // No need for taxonomy param when you pass a term object
```

Comment: I've since this issue in WooCommerce too - it really annoys me when devs don't make the effort to check these things. Good on you @Jonathan for using debug bar ;)

Comment: Just to note, if the object is not passed, and the category/term ID is passed or the slug is passed, `get_term_link` uses `get_term` and `get_term_by` respectively to get the category/term object ;-)

Comment: Also, this does not come down to cache, as the results are not cached, check the [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/)

Comment: Yay, works great! Code even looks better...