# Output link to category from WP_Query loop of woocommerce products

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a WP_Query that outputs featured products. For each product I would also like to link to the category of that product, but I'm not sure how.

I think this is close to being my answer, but I'm not sure how to put it all together. [How to get category link without a database query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204885/how-to-get-category-link-without-a-database-query)

My query so far is:

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
        'field'    => 'name',
        'terms'    => 'featured',
        'operator' => 'IN'
      ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 8
  );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<ul class="product-list">

  <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
  <li class="product-list__item">

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>"
      <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>

    Link to the product category here!
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_the_term_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/) to output a comma-separated list of links to product categories:

```
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <li class="product-list__item">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>

        <?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat', '', ', ' ); ?>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Note that when you're inside 'the loop' (i.e. between `$loop->the_post();` and `endwhile`) you don't need to pass an ID to `get_permalink()`, you can just use `the_permalink()`.

Also, in your code you're missing the last `>` from the opening anchor tag, make sure to fix that.

Comment: Thank you, this works great. Also thanks for the tip on `the_permalink`. Much appreciated.